# Querying a Nullable bool in C#

Tags: c#, resharper, nullable

I've come across a curious problem with the following code. It compiles fine although [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) highlights the code segment `(autorefresh == null)`, notifying me *Expression is always false*

```c#
bool? autorefresh = Properties.Settings.Default.autorefresh;
autorefresh = (autorefresh == null) ? false : autorefresh;
Enabled = (bool)autorefresh;
```

Any ideas how better to get around this problem?

**Edit 07/02/2012 16:52**

```c#
Properties.Settings.Default.autorefresh
```

The above is a `bool`, not a `string`.

Comment: Isn't autorefresh a non nullable boolean? (in which case it will never be null)

Comment: The autorefresh is nullable type which means that autorefresh.Value can be null. I think that you can do like this  enable = (!autorefresh.HasValue) ? false : autorefresh.Value;

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think what you want is:

```
Enabled = Properties.Settings.Default.autorefresh ?? false;
```

In light of your comments, it appears you were unneccessarily assigning the value of `autorefresh` to a `Nullable<bool>`. In terms of safeguarding the data, the `Settings` will return you the default value for that type if it is invalid or missing (which would be `false` for `boolean`'s). Therefore, your code should simply be:

```
Enabled = Properties.Settings.Default.autorefresh;
```

Comment: This is not possible, the compiler complains of the following "Left operand of the '??' operator should be of reference or nullable type"

Comment: @wonea, looks like `autorefresh` is a plain `bool` then. Is there a reason why you're assigning it to a `Nullable<bool>` variable?

Comment: @wonea is `autorefresh` a nullable bool? If not then that's the problem. Your question (and code) seems to imply that it is. However, I just ran a small test app there added in a boolean setting and it gave me back a straight bool. If that is the case then there is no need to use a nullable bool at all simple set enabled to be the value of `Properties.Settings.Default.autorefresh`

Comment: It comes part of the application config, and I want to safeguard against the configuration being changed and missing values.

Comment: @wonea `Properties.Settings.Default.autorefresh` will be `false` if the setting is missing... because it's non-nullable and the default value of a Boolean is `false`.

Comment: @wonea - If it's being set in the `Settings` then there is no need to safeguard it, it is done automatically. It should return the default for the data type (which should be false for a boolean).

Answer (score 3):

Reason it through:

```c#
bool? autorefresh = Properties.Settings.Default.autorefresh; 
                 // ^^^ this is a non-nullable Boolean
```

`Properties.Settings.Default.autorefresh` is non-nullable, therefore it will be either true or false.

Therefore the nullable local `autorefresh` will also be either true or false, since it is initialized to a value that is either true or false.

```c#
autorefresh = (autorefresh == null) ? false : autorefresh; 
                       // ^^^^ therefore this test will never succeed
```

Therefore this is equivalent to:

```c#
autorefresh = autorefresh;
```

which is obviously pointless. (And, as others have pointed out, `autorefresh ?? false` is the better way to write this code anyway.)

The question is: why do you have the local variable in the first place? Why not simply say:

```c#
Enabled = Properties.Settings.Default.autorefresh;
```

?

Comment: After some discussion (see comments on my post) the reason the user was assigning the value to a `Nullable<bool>` was to safeguard against the setting being missing or invalid. However, as explained this will never be the case as `Settings` will return the default for the type if it cannot determine the value from the config file. I think perhaps @wonea was getting confused between using `Settings` and `AppSettings` which does allow null values.

Answer (score 1):

```
  bool? autorefresh = Properties.Settings.Default.autorefresh ?? false;
```

It is safe to make these following comparisons with nullable operators

```
autorefresh == null
```

or you may also compare

```
autorefresh == true
```

or

```
autorefresh == false
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also jut do this:

```
 Enabled = Properties.Settings.Default.autorefresh.GetValueOrDefault(false);
```

No need to to check for nulls if the nullable value can do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Nullables have some interesting behavior.  I'd have to dig a bit to get you the exact reasons for what you see.  Regardless, the correct way to test a nullable is to use the .HasValue method.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
bool? autorefresh = Properties.Settings.Default.autorefresh;
Enabled = (!autorefresh.HasValue) ? false : autorefresh.Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

The autorefresh is nullable type which means that autorefresh.Value can be null. 
I think that you can do like this

enable = !autorefresh.HasValue ? false : autorefresh.Value;